# Upgrade install only leaves files new to the new version, deleting files common to both old and new

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, upgrade, web-deployment-project

I have a Web Application and Deployment Project that was originally built in VS 2008 that installed version 1.51 of my application. I am now using VS 2010 (and my app requires .Net 4 and Installer 4.5) and updated my application and the deployment project to 1.52. If I run the setup on a virgin system, everything works as expected.

If I run the 1.52 setup on a system with 1.51 already installed, instead of ending up with a full copy of 1.52 at the end of the setup, all files common to both 1.51 and 1.52 are deleted (regardless of whether or not they differ between versions), only files that did not exist in 1.51 at all are deployed, and my CustomActions are not run. The setup claims to have completed successfully. I ran the setup with the /l*vx option and used Wilogutl.exe to analyze the log file and it says "No error found" and "No solution needed".

I have RemovePreviousVersions set to True, same UpgradeCode for both versions, updated ProductCode and Version. If I set RemovePreviousVersions to false, then the install of 1.52 on a system with 1.51 already on it seems to give me the desired result.

Shouldn't it work with RemovePreviousVersions set to true?

What potential problems should I look for when doing an upgrade install if I leave RemovePreviousVersions set to false?

- Mark

Comment: It looks to me like the removal of the old version is not doing the removal right away, but is queuing it for later--perhaps after the reboot with the PendingFileRename Registry values. Does the install suggest you need to reboot? If so, you would want to remove the old version, reboot, then install the new version and reboot again... fun!

Comment: The install does not suggest that I reboot.

I found this thread on Microsoft Connect, which helped some, but it doesn't completely resolve the problem: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/559575/problem-with-installing-and-removing-previous-versions-after-upgrading-my-setup-project-to-vs2010

Answer (score 1):

Have you done something to the setup project that has changed all the component GUIDs. If the GUIDs of the components are not identical between the old and new versions, the component reference counting mechanism will be broken. So version 1 lays down component 1, with file 1. On upgrade the new version lays down component 2 which also lays down file 1. Then the RemoveExistingProducts action will look for any components that can be removed. Since component 1's ref count is down to 1 the installer will try to remove it, including File 1.

Answer (score 0):

Change your upgrade to a major upgrade and move the RemoveExistingProducts standard action before InstallInitialize in the InstallExecuteSequence.

As Stephen Connolly writes, you have probably messed up the component referencing. This makes upgrades unreliable or downright impossible. You can "decouple" the new and older version by using major upgrades because a major upgrade isn't an upgrade, but an uninstall of the old version and an install of the new version in a chained sequence.